# using pi and e constants from Z3 API

Tags: java, z3, smt, constraint-programming

How does one use trigonometric functions like sin and cos and the constant Pi from the Z3 java API?

If I use the java API like so:

```
    Solver s = context.getSolver()
    s.add(z3.parseSMTLIB2String(
              "(declare-fun theta () Real)\n"+
              "(declare-fun offset () Real)\n"+
              "(assert (> (cos theta) (/ 1 pi)))\n"
     //a sequence of empty arrays
```

Then z3 will attempt to reason about pi and cosine.

But I cannot figure out how to declare that in the java API. There is no `mkCos` or `pi` constant available. So how would one encode this with the java API? Is it perhaps a simple over-sight that this function and the constant `pi` are not exposed?

Comment: This is probably not Java specific; they probably haven't been added to any of the APIs. If I'm not mistaken, this line of work was never finished, so I'd be careful about the semantics/behavior of these operators as well. For instance, some may be treated as completely uninterpreted functions.

Comment: (e and pi are in the C API, so their raw form is available in Native.java; look for rcfMkPi and rcfMkE.)

Comment: hah, well in attempting to hit that method and the necessary wrappers via reflection I got a good ol' `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` that killed the JVM. I would vastly prefer it if I could just log this as a bug with you guys and have you add it --or, alternatively, maybe ill re-tool to build smt-lib2 strings rather than using the actual API. a gist: https://gist.github.com/Groostav/a7aa6e0729734f6f94889c034074700b

Comment: Sure, those are the low-level C functions that pass pointers around, so easy to get wrong. Feel free to log a bug/issue, but it may take a little bit of time until we get around to adding those functions.

Comment: Thanks Christoph, I created [a new issue on github.com/Z3Solver/Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1327)