# Z3Py how to use Pi and e

Tags: z3, z3py

Is it possible to use `pi`, `e` and other non-algebraic real numbers in Z3Py?

I wouldn't want to run any C program, but directly from the Z3 Python API

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46886468/1166898

Comment: @CJDennis duplicate target does not have an answer.

Comment: @svgrafov If it did I would have raised a close flag. If looks like one of the contributors answered in a comment.

Comment: @CJDennis that's a one-year-old question and it is suggested to look at the native Java API. I don't know if there's any similar in Python and I've asked if it was possible to avoid it anyway (because I had read that question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-algebraic numbers are usually not supported by SMT solvers. Having said that, you can get `pi` in z3 indirectly via trigonometric functions, (`sin`, `cos` etc.); but the support is incomplete. (Meaning that the solver is most likely to return `unknown` for most inputs.)

See this answer for a related question: [Support of trigonometric functions ( e.g.: cos, tan) in Z3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433210/support-of-trigonometric-functions-e-g-cos-tan-in-z3)